# Wanted a tool for stripping out comments from C# source

Tags: c#, obfuscation

Does anyone know such a tool?
Both support of "//" and "/* */" is needed.

It'd be nice if it supports aspx-files also.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to **remove** comments???

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Most answers I can think of suggest it's a bad idea.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a regular expression. Comments in C# are not _that_ complicated.

Comment: If you grab others' files and would like to make them yours, you don't need to remove the comments to help you better understand them. If those files are in fact written by you, then why do you think removing comments makes them better? If you plan to share some files with others, why not leave your comments there to guide them? I could hardly find a reason why you plan to do something that does not worth the while :)

Comment: Comments do not make it into the compiled product, in case that is what you were thinking. The only reason to obfuscate the source like this is because you have sold it to someone else? I have had to work with code like this in the past, and it is a PITA, so i would never help someone else perpetuate the same crime against humanity :)

Comment: Guys, I need to remove comments because I must give sources to my customer. But I must give only sources not comments.
Why the hell I can't strip them out?

Comment: Do you really think this is a good idea? If I were your customer, I would not be very happy seeing unreadable obfuscated code.

Comment: 2marc_s: I accept answers when it does solve my problem, not just trying to get scores.

Comment: 2stribika: it's not obfuscated ! It's just plain code without comments. 
Image you have developed a software and then your customer made a constract for supporting (of software is developed by you) with another company. Why not to deprive them of your comments. It's fair

Comment: @Shrike - Looking at your questions, plenty of them have answers that resolve the issue, but aren't accepted.  If people legitimately solve your issue, but have no chance for reward, it makes your questions much less appealing to answer.

Comment: @Shrike: This may not answer your question directly, but just a side note; releasing your code with comments would only increase your products' as well as company's marketability/reach en masse. If your code is nicely commented, "the" person who will maintain the code is always going to have a good impression of the company; which is a good thing - and again is going to increase your company's, well, 'technical-persona'. Besides, with or without comments, the Maintainer will fix the code 'anyway'; so leaving them with good energy(the comments in this case) is again a good thing.

Comment: @driis: Doing it *correctly* is harder than you think.  For example, suppose you have #if X\n /* \n #endif \n int x; \n #if Y\n */ \n  // z \n #endif \n-- how many comments are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Semantic Designs C# Formatter](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Formatters/CSharpFormatter.html).  The Formatter can pretty-print your code to make it prettier, or fidelity print your code to preserve the way it looks.  It has an option to control whether comments are retained or not.

Comment: Thanks for the link, looks interesting. Do you have experience in using it?

Comment: I'm asking because there's no trial version on their site (only money back)

Comment: I *wrote* it. Actually, you can get an evaluation download (no charge) to play with.  Just ask at the site.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you're looking for: [Comment Remover](http://cnbthcommentremover.codeplex.com/)

Or you can do this with Replace tool in Visual Studio. Just create proper Regular expression for searching comments

Comment: Do not create a proper regex - it wont work. Create a VS flavored regex instead ;)

Comment: Pretty raw utility, doesn't understand masks/folders. And doesn't work :(